# Multiple databases v/s Multiple collections - MongoDB 3.2

Tags: mongodb, database

I know this question has been asked a number of times here. However, I am unable to find a satisfying answer and reach on a conclusion.

This question is specifically for Mongo DB version 3.2. Should I have separate DBs and collection for different apps, or just one DB with all collections within it?

To simplify it further, let’s say I have about 15-20k apps on a server. Is it advisable to create a different database for each of these apps (with 10 collections/app), or create just one database and store all collections (20k apps * 10 collections = 200k collections) in it?

Also, this would be called from single Node app so need to consider the performance on having multi DB connections.

Comment: No of collections does not matter in single database, it is just a storage space.

Answer (score 0):

Should I have separate DBs and collection for different apps, or just one DB with all collections within it.

As I understand there is not any concrete answer or any concrete algorithm for this question It depends on no of connections with the database actually.
No of connections depends on the upcoming concurrent requests count so first see logically that Is it really worth to create a different database for each of these apps 
Or another way (with 10 collections/app)

second way is you can judge the response time with some load testing (If possible)

Comment: The question is about separating the content to the level where the optimum performance is achieved from MongoDB without any compromise. Wanted to understand whether connection pool between multiple databases (sharing connection through node app) is an issue or it won't affect the performance